# Extracting a part of URL

Tags: php, url

I have a hyperlink in my excel sheet say:

```
http://abc.com/u?/abc,143
```

When i open this link it turns out something like this:

```
http://abc.com/cdm4/document.php?CISOROOT=/abc&CISOPTR=160&CISOSHOW=143
```

I get a new number for every link. In the above example it is "160" (CISOPTR=160).

How can i extract these numbers for every link and store it?

Comment: I did not try anything. I am looking for how can i do it?

Comment: Wow, never thought I would see a CONTENTdm URL show up on Stack Overflow.  Not too many people out there unfortunate enough to be dealing with those...

Comment: @Jack: Sure, i will try something now.

Comment: @JackManey I have not asked for any code here. I just wanted to know how can it be done.

Comment: @Michael Did you have a experience using CONTENTdm URL?

Comment: @Dumb_Shock Yes - Until a few months ago, I was employed by the parent organization of the [Minnesota Digital Library](http://www.mndigital.org)

Comment: @Michael: I am trying to extract all the content in my schools contentdm website.Good to know that you worked for contentdm.

Comment: @Dumb_Shock Worked _with_, not worked _for_.  We had a project that used a Google Search appliance to crawl all our CDM urls and fetch thumbnails. It never really worked and was discontinued, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after `.php?` is usually a collection of GET request parameters. You can access them by using the global `$_GET` array, like so:

`$myvar = $_GET['CISOPTR'];`

Things to keep in mind:

1. If you are storing that data in a database remember to escape that data (use `intval()` for numbers and `mysql_real_escape_string()` for strings)
2. Do not ever trust that data - it's a rule of thumb. This data can be malformed or maliciously modified. Always check it before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$_GET`:

```
echo $_GET['CISOPTR']; // 160
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `$_GET` as Sarfraz suggests, you can parse the URL as follows:

```
$return = parse_url( 'http://abc.com/cdm4/document.php?CISOROOT=/kmag&CISOPTR=160&CISOSHOW=143');
parse_str( $return['query'], $pieces);
echo $pieces['CISOPTR']; // 160
```